# Determine "real" data type from plain text data

Tags: r

I have raw data as follows:

```
C1    C2        C3     C4
"1"   "6464"    "abc"  "1"
"2"   "3434"    "def"  "0"
"3"   "3434"    "ghi"  "1"
"4"   "asd"     "jkl"  "1"
"5"   "4565"    "mno"  "0"
```

I know I can use *str*, *type*, *mode*, *class* etc. to determine the data type, but is there any package in R that can estimate what the predominant type would be based on the raw data content itself?

E.g. I can see C1 would be numeric (although it would be reported as char), C2 would be largely numeric, except for one character value, C3 is character and C4 would be numeric (or possibly logical if it only contains 0/1). I can go and write functions to work this all out, just don't want to reinvent the wheel if it exists?

The end goal is to write a clean/convert function to (largely) automatically fix raw data.

Comment: Is this data you are reading into R, or typing in? The base read.* functions and the readr::read_* functions do well at guessing types. And the readr functions can be used directly on text if the data aren't in a file you are trying to import.

Comment: It can be either. Sometimes it comes from SAS or CSV. Let's assume I already have it in a data.frame, irrespective of where I got it from.

Comment: @ChrisHolbrook the specific numeric part is, thanks for pointing that out. The rest of my question is not in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `readr::parse_guess` to automatically guess the type of a vector.

Here is an example

```
# Read data as data.table of character vectors
df <- read.table(text =
    'C1    C2        C3     C4
1   6464    abc  1
2   3434    def  0
3   3434    ghi  1
4   asd     jkl  1
5   4565    mno  0', header = T, colClasses = "character")

library(purrr)
library(readr)
map_df(df, ~parse_guess(.x))
## A tibble: 5 x 4
#     C1 C2    C3       C4
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
#1     1 6464  abc       1
#2     2 3434  def       0
#3     3 3434  ghi       1
#4     4 asd   jkl       1
#5     5 4565  mno       0
```